# Cross domain ajax hits error even that the status came back is 200

Tags: ajax, cross-domain

I am sending cross domain ajax request, the response comes back with status 200. I also see that the request arrives to the server.

I have this in my server:

```
context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
```

This is on the client:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: this.SERVER + url,
        data: data,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        success: function (a, b) {
            debugger;
            alert("sdsd");
        },error : function(a,b) {
            debugger;
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
```

this is the request from the chrome browser

[image]

In firefox its I get the error:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:2000/PageHandler.ashx. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My wild guess is that since you are sending the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header you cannot put `*` in `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. Try specifying the origin as that of your JavaScript client.

I am basing this on the following piece of information from the Mozilla Developer Networks Documentation on [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin):

> The origin parameter specifies a URI that may access the resource. 
>   The browser must enforce this.  For requests without credentials, the
>   server may specify "*" as a wildcard, thereby allowing any origin to
>   access the resource.